# Synonymous phrase for "nothing but"?

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I'm wondering if there is a synonymous phrase that I can use instead of "nothing but." Here is the context:

> ....which is often backed by *nothing but* one's unsubstantial reasoning or particular fondness.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/nothing%20but?s=t) is a link to a thesaurus.

- ...which is often backed by one's unsubstantial reasoning or particular fondness *alone*.
- ...which is often backed *only* by one's unsubstantial reasoning or particular fondness.
- ...which is often backed *solely*/*entirely*/*merely* by one's unsubstantial reasoning or particular fondness.

Comment: Perfect... Just what I needed! (I didn't think that this would be in the thesaurus lol :P)

Answer (score 0):

As above, also perhaps **in its entirety**, eg which is often backed by one's unsubstantial reasoning or particular findness, in its entirety.

Just my 2¢